# Spring: Create new instance of bean for each call of get method

Tags: java, spring, cloning

I have next situation:
`Connection manager` should have each time one object of `ConnectionServer` and new objects of `DataBean`
So, I have created these beans and configured out it spring xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <bean id="dataBena" class="com.test.DataBean" scope="prototype"/>
    <bean id="servCon" class="com.test.ServerCon"/>
    <!--<bean id="test" class="com.test.Test"/>-->
     <context:component-scan base-package="com.test"/>
</beans>
```

and added scope `prototype` for `DataBean`

After this I've created simple util/component class called Test

```
@Component
public class Test {

    @Autowired
    private DataBean bean;
    @Autowired
    private ServerCon server;

    public DataBean getBean() {
        return bean.clone();
    }

    public ServerCon getServer() {
        return server;
    }

}
```

BUT, Each time of calling getBean() method I am cloning this bean, and this is the problem to me.
Can I do it from spring configuration **without usning clone method**?
Thanks.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You are looking for [lookup method](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lookup-method-injection) functionality in Spring. The idea is that you provide an abstract method like this:

```
@Component
public abstract class Test {
  public abstract DataBean getBean();
}
```

And tell Spring that it should implement it at runtime:

```
<bean id="test" class="com.test.Test">
  <lookup-method name="getBean" bean="dataBean"/>
</bean>
```

Now every time you call `Test.getBean` you will actually call Spring-generated method. This method will ask `ApplicationContext` for `DataBean` instance. If this bean is `prototype`-scoped, you will get new instance each time you call it.

I wrote about this feature [here](http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.com/2010/08/creating-prototype-spring-beans-on.html).

Comment: Just add [cglib.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/cglib/cglib/2.2.2/cglib-2.2.2.jar) to your CLASSPATH.

Comment: How would you handle this if `DataBean` is a generic and if inside it had a `Service<T>` which is `@Autowired`  depending on the `<T>` type?

Comment: Use ObjectFactory from spring. look for examples and plenty are available in net. Make sure that @Scope("prototype") given to your class.